# UIScrollView jumping when scrolled

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm using an UILabel inside an UIScrollView, but when the view is loaded I don't see the text. Then if I start scrolling, the text appears.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [scrollView addSubview:mainLabel];
    [scrollView setAutoresizesSubviews:true];

    NSString *text = [textList objectAtIndex:(currentTextId)];

    CGFloat width = [mainLabel frame].size.width;
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont: [mainLabel font]
                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                             lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake (0, 0, width, textSize.height);
    [mainLabel setFrame:labelFrame];
    [mainLabel setText:text];
}
```

Comment: Are you using a nib created in Xcode 4.6.x? If so, it may be using autolayout.

Comment: Yes I am, and it was in autolayout. Now I have disabled it, set the scrollView contentSize and frame and it does not scroll any more. I'm looking for what is wrong in my code.

Comment: If it doesn't scroll, that's because you are setting the contextSize incorrectly. It must be bigger than the scroll view size - otherwise, there is nothing to scroll.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_creating_a_scroll_view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should set the `frame` and also the `contentSize` of the scrollView

Answer (score 0):

You should be explicitly setting the scroll views `contentSize` so that it knows how big the label is.